# How to place images on Path2D objects in Java Graphics

Tags: java, image, textures, graphics2d, cube

I have a `Path2D.Double()` Shape and I would like to know how to place an image on the shape. I am ideally looking for an API which can do this for me, But any method that is not ridiculously complicated should be fine.

The shape I wish to draw upon is a 2D Isometric cube (In example code the cube is not rotated therefore not really isometric but thats not really a problem), If that is of any useful infomation to anyone, and I create my shape as follows

Trying to add a png / jpg image (dosent matter i can convert between the two) Of a brick like image. I dont think it matters what the content of the image is.

```
Path2D shape = new Path2D.Double();
shape.moveTo(x, y);
for(int i=0; i<xcords.length;i++){
    shape.lineTo(xcords[i], ycords[i]);
}
shape.closePath();
```

Code to re-create scenario

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main extends JPanel {

    static int WIDTH;
    static int HEIGHT;

    Path2D shape;

    int[] xcords = {0,100,100,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,100,100,  0,       0,  0,     100,100,  0,  0,100,100,100,100,100,100,  0,  0,100,   0,  0,  0};
    int[] ycords = {0,  0,100,100,  0,  0,100,100,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,       0,100,     100,  0,  0,100,100,100,  0,  0,100,100,100,100,100, 100,  0,  0};
    int[] zcords = {0,  0,  0,  0,  0,100,100,  0,  0,100,100,  0,  0,     100,100,     100,100,100,100,100,  0,  0,100,100,  0,  0,100,100, 100,100,  0};

    public Main(){
        shape = new Path2D.Double();
        shape.moveTo(300, 300);
        for (int i=0; i<xcords.length;i++){
            xcords[i] = xcords[i] - zcords[i];
            ycords[i] = ycords[i] - zcords[i];
        }
        for (int i=0; i<xcords.length;i++){
            shape.lineTo(300+xcords[i],300+ycords[i]);
        }
        shape.closePath();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.draw(shape);

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        WIDTH = (int) screenSize.getWidth();
        HEIGHT = (int) screenSize.getHeight();
        Main main = new Main();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("360 ATTACK");
        frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.add(main);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes thats exactly what i am trying to do and i will improve my answer right now with your template.

Comment: Please read my edited queston.

Comment: Thank you, I'll see if I can get my IDE cranked up, but while waiting for that... what image are you trying to place on the drawing? Can you upload that to your question?

Comment: This process of decorating a shape with an image is called adding a "texture".  (Might help in searching for an answer.)

Comment: Added more infomation to my question Hovercraft, And yes i know whiskey :D Still didnt find any good answers.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Have you read my updated question?